# Trouble Merging Object with State in Angular NgRx

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, ngrx

I read this tutorial [on creating a NgRx store](https://medium.com/frontend-fun/angular-ngrx-a-clean-and-clear-introduction-4ed61c89c1fc) so I created a simple store with the following shape.

```
export const initialState: IState = {
  app: initialAppState
};

export function getInitialState(): IState {
  return initialState;
}

export interface IApp {
  id?: string;
  testMode?: boolean;
  authenticated?: boolean;
  user?: User;
  role?: string;
}

export interface IAppState {
  app: IApp;
}

export const initialAppState: IAppState = {
  app: {
    id: null,
    testMode: false,
    authenticated: false,
    user: null,
    role: 'END_USER'
  }
};
```

It has one action `PatchApp` with a reducer that looks like this

```
export const appReducers = (state = initialAppState, action: AppActions): IAppState => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case AppActionTypes.PatchApp: {
      return { ...state, app: action.payload };
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Now to me, this seems super simple.   We have an initial state that is stored in the `app` property.    If we get a payload to update the `authenticated` property on the existing state, I would expect the reducer to overwrite just that property instead of the entire state.

But when I step through with the debugger, I can see the state get's updated with just the property that gets passed in.

So if I have the initial state like this:

```
export const initialAppState: IAppState = {
  app: {
    id: null,
    testMode: false,
    authenticated: false,
    user: null,
    role: 'END_USER'
  }
};
```

then I do `PatchApp` with `{authenticated: true, id: 'someid'}`, I would expect the `action.payload` to overwrite/merge/patch the existing object.

Instead what happens is the entire store get's overwritten with JUST the property.   So after doing the afformentioned patch app, we would have just the `authenticated` and `id` props set.

Any idea why my reducer isn't behaving as expected?   I read an [article from Flavio Copes](https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-merge-objects-javascript/) and don't see anything where I'm going wrong.

I also tried using `Object.assign()` to merge the objects.

```
return Object.assign({}, state, { app: action.payload });
```

I have a CodeSandbox that illustrates the problem I'm trying to solve.

https://codesandbox.io/s/oxj7xx5n35?fontsize=14

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure whether I got right what you're trying to do, but it seems that you want to patch just the `app` part of the state. If so, you should do it like this:

```js
export const appReducers = (state = initialAppState, action: AppActions): IAppState => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case AppActionTypes.PatchApp: {
      return { 
        ...state, 
        app: {...state.app, ...action.payload} 
      };
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: An important thing here is to use spread operator on action too. `{..state.app, action.payload}` is not valid